# Add multiple sizes of splash screen in ionic cordova when migrating to android 12 and above

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, android-12, android-splashscreen, ionic-cordova

Am trying to migrate ionic cordova app to android 12 (api 32). Cannot use `<splash>` tags anymore. instead that I should use `<preference name="AndroidWindowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon" value="path to xml/png" />`.

Previously I generated resources files with `cordova-res`, So it automatically adding resources files into `config.xml` like below,

```
    <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
```

How do I do this with new way of adding splash screen..?

```
<preference name="AndroidWindowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon" value="path to xml/png" />
```

Comment: check this
https://ionic.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/7891143965975-Migrating-to-Cordova-Android-11

Answer (score 9):

**Step 1**: create an svg of 288x288px. With the same background colour as the page your loading the icon on and put your logo in the middle of this square. Your logo needs to fit within 192px. Like in this image: [image: icon size]

Step 2: Use android studio to create an .xml file.
To do this, open a new project with 'empty activity'. right click on the res folder, go to new -> Vector Asset. Select your image from step 1. going through the wizard should result in generating one .xml file.

Step 3: add this .xml file to your resources in Cordova and link to it in your config.xml like so:

`<preference name="AndroidWindowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon" value="path to yourIcon.xml" />`

The xml file has dp's, which stands for density independent pixels. From that I conclude that it should work independent from screen size and resolution.

link to splashscreen page in android docs (where I got the image from): https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen

Comment: This seemed to work and look ok (not as good as before where we could have larger images) on the phone, but did not seem to scale up when running on a tablet. Have done a [separate post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75934884/android-splash-screen-image-does-not-seem-to-scale-up-when-running-on-a-larger) asking about this.

Comment: you can use PNG in config.xml you not need make all this conversions

Comment: The PNG is, indeed, useable, but you'll probably still need to resize it to fit the described dimensions. I tried just swapping the tag and keeping the original file we had for the new splash screen, but it got cut out. Since I would need to do some image editing, I decided to just grab the original SVG and create the vector - it's even lighter than the SVG that it's created from.

Answer (score 8):

I just found out that android has changed the SplashScreen API.. So here is the new dimensions for [new splash screen logo](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/splash-screen#splash_screen_dimensions)
So looks like we have to give up on splash screen image. You can set the app logo with this preference. Keep in mind that the logo will be displayed in a circled container as in dimension page.

```
<preference name="AndroidWindowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon" value="path to xml/png" />
```

You can change background color with

```
<preference name="AndroidWindowSplashScreenBackground" value="#b51b1b" />
```

Comment: Thank you soo much, i been fighting up with this for hours. 
>This works for Cordova too!

Comment: As hard as I have tried, this doesn't seem to work for us - the background color works great, but the picture never shows.

Comment: @igorsantos07 https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen/ It's working for me perfectly. Did you try the above answer?

Comment: @Pumayk26 actually, I forgot I made this comment. I cannot edit it anymore (should I delete it?), but it looks like this is a device-specific problem - the same code works great on my Samsung tablet, but won't show the icon on my OnePlus phone. I realized I should try another device after I saw a complaint on GitHub from someone with another uncommon brand of Android device. Cordova being Cordova, I guess ‍♂️ Sadly I cannot take my downvote either, unless the answer is edited (weird new policy?)

Comment: update: my problem seems to be, actually, with splash icons on Android 12 only? - https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/issues/1669

Answer (score -1):

I tried the method above but got an error, because I couldn't find the xml directory that I created.

I created a layout folder and moved the xml to that folder:

```
 platforms\android\app\src\main\res\layout\splash.xml
```

then change the themes xml file :

```
platforms\android\app\src\main\res\values\themes.xml
```

replace string number 5 :

```
<item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@layout/splash</item>
```

that way the splashscreen icon can change. I made an xml splashscreen using the website https://svg2vector.com, it's very easy just input the SVG file and it becomes xml.

Comment: nothing inside `platforms/` should be changed, since those are generated files.