# Android splash screen image does not seem to scale up when running on a larger (tablet) screen

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an Android Ionic Cordova application (I am not sure if it is specific to a Cordova app) where I have followed the second answer from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73370569/add-multiple-sizes-of-splash-screen-in-ionic-cordova-when-migrating-to-android-1) to create a new splash screen.

As suggested, I created an svg and used Android studio get get it imbedded into an XML, which I then point to in the config.xml. So in the build Android project I have the following..

```
<preference name="AndroidWindowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon" value="resources/android/splash2/splash.xml" />
```

I did try to make the images too big (as it use to have the application name etc), so I know I need to make it a bit smaller as I can see it is just cropped, but the main issue is that the "circle" is appears in does not seem to scale up on a tablet.

Eg on a phone I see (ignore the fact the image is cropped, I can deal with this)

[image]

but on a tablet, I get (ignore the rectangle I drew around the screen boundaries)

[image]

I would have thought the image should be a little larger on the bigger screen, especially as it is a scalable image (i.e. in the xml I see it is made up of a bunch of `<path>` tags?

For Cordova specific I have updated to Cordova 11 as per [these instructions](https://ionic.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/7891143965975-Migrating-to-Cordova-Android-11), except I have tried at target API 31 for now.

Should this images scale up for tablets?